# VSCode Portable disable auto-expansion of folded blocks

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-python

In VSCode Portable, is there a method/setting to disable automatic expansion of folded functions (or other types of foldable blocks, I guess) on start-up? That is, if I fold a function block, close VSCode and open the file the next day again, that the block remains folded?

Comment: derp https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/169270. if you raise an issue ticket, please ping me with a link to it.

Comment: @starball: Sorry for the late reply. Issue raised under https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/189610 together with mentioning persistent cursor and screen locations (which are also reset) upon closing and reopening VSCode.

Comment: the VS Code maintainers could not reproduce this issue. please either provide more details on how to reproduce, or this question should be closed as "not reproducible".